# Facebook blue highlight for a multiline ASP.NET textbox

Tags: asp.net, css, facebook, autocomplete, textbox

I am trying to implement Facebook autocomplete functionality after a user types @ for a multiline ASP.Net textbox, including highlighting the selected text (this would only be a part of text inside the textbox).

My question is: is it possible to apply different styles inside a textbox or how does Facebook highlight in blue what the user choose from the completion list? How can I achieve the same result with my textbox? As far as I know one cannot apply different css inside the same textbox.

Please help & encourage me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to apply different styles inside a textbox

No.

> or how does Facebook highlight in blue what the user choose from the completion list?

*contentEditable* is your keyword. This is a mechanism implemented in newer browsers to make parts of a document “editable”; and with HTML5 is has gotten standardized.

Comment: Facebook does not use contentEditable for this effect. They overlay the text-only textbox on top of a DOM element that contains text equivalent to the contents of the textbox. They then "highlight" words in the textbox by adding background styles to specific words in the DOM element. See http://www.strangeplanet.fr/work/jquery-highlighttextarea/ for another implementation example.